# how to let users know about upload progress to google cloud files

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I'd like to use google cloud files, but I'm wondering how to show a progress bar to users.

How to monitor upload progress ?
So we can display some kind of progress bar to user...

TIA,
tom

Comment: Are you referring to when **you** upload a file using the Cloud Console? Or that you want to upload a file and share the status with your application's users?

Comment: First I'm complete newbie, I didnt have a look at php api. I'd like to know if there is a mean to show upload progress to end users. Upload to php server is handled by the php application and there are a few solutions to show progress (php extension, ajax, html5 api I think), but then when the file is on the server the backend has to upload the file to google cloud storage, the latter is the upload I'd like to share the progress with users. Does google cloud storage provide some kind of uploading progress feedback ?

Comment: OK, php curl seems to have a progressfunction option, which lets provide a progress callback. So I would just have then to put progress value into a session variable and ask for it with ajax calls.